# css for large backgrounds at different screen sizes without getting scroll bars

Tags: html, css, background-image

Maybe this is a no-brainer but i cant see the solution right now :)
I got a 960px centered content div and now i need to add a teaser which contains 2 parts, a huge background with wide shadows (2000px wide) and some foreground pics max 960px wide. 
If i add the 2000px background my chrome automatically applies horizontal scrollbars because of my low 1280px resolution. What I need is that it ignores the scrollbars and let the image just get out of bounds and only been seen on higher resolutions

```
<div id="cotainer!> <!--! #container 960px wide, margin: auto, overflow:visible --->

  <div id="stage"></div> <!--! has the 2000px background -->

</div> <!--! end of #container -->
```

I hope i was able to describe my problem properly, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you just combine your background images into a single image, and set it as the `background-image` on the `body`?

Comment: The first answer that comes to mind in this situation is to set width and height 100% and overflow:hidden on the element with the huge background.

Comment: Are you using an actual background image, or just a div that looks like `<div><img></div>`? A normal background image does not count for sizing calculations, while the img-tag-in-div DOES.

Comment: `background-image:` will never cause a scroll bar, do you sure you are using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this wrong. If you want a wide background image, you'll want to apply the background to a wrapper, and add the container inside the wrapper:

```
<div id="#wrapper" style="background-image:(url...);background-repeat:no-repeat;">
     <div id="container"> STUFF </div>
</div>
```

This will work so long as the wrapper is not enclosed by any narrower div (it will expand to fit the width of the page).

Comment: but doesnt the big wrapper cause the browser to add scrollbars?

Comment: No, because as long as you don't set the width the div will expand to fit the width of the page but no further. If the page gets wider or narrower the div will shrink and grow with it. Background images don't affect the layout of the block it is applied to, so the width of the div will always be with width of the screen, and as much background as will fit in in the screen will be displayed.

Comment: thanks, but now i got the problem that the background is never really centered because u only see the part of the background from 0 till the width of the window (1280,1600,1920 etc) but its never really centered except at a screen resolution of 2000px. is there any possibility to center the background?

Comment: css - background-position:center